# Wait for resources to complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I know how to begin a Process and how to wait it for exit but that seems that it does not work properly for resources.I have the followning lines of code

```
 string path = @"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\MyFolder";
              Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            if (checkbox1.Checked)
            {
                var exe1 = new Resource("SOLUTION.Resources.First.exe",
                Path.Combine(path, "1st.exe"));
                Process.Start(exe1.FilePath);

            }
            if (checkbox2.Checked)
            {
               var exe2 = new Resource("SOLUTION.Resources.Second.exe",
                Path.Combine(path, "Second.exe"));
                Process.Start(exe2.FilePath);
            }
```

But when I start the process both of them start together how to set each of them wait for the previous to be completed?

---

*Thank you all for your support so far*

Comment: How do you normally wait for it to exit?  `Process.Start` is not a blocking call AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string path = @"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\MyFolder";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

if (checkbox1.Checked)
{
    var exe1 = new Resource("SOLUTION.Resources.First.exe",
    Path.Combine(path, "1st.exe"));
    Process.Start(exe1.FilePath).WaitForExit();
}
if (checkbox2.Checked)
{
    var exe2 = new Resource("SOLUTION.Resources.Second.exe",
    Path.Combine(path, "Second.exe"));
    Process.Start(exe2.FilePath).WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: of courses that's why I writed "MARKED" have a nice day